# jQuery PrevAll() selector fail

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab and display the value of the input when the button is clicked.

```js
$('.nextBtn').click(function() {
  alert($('this').prevAll('input[type=tel]').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step" id="step1">
  <h2>How old are you?</h2>
  Answer: <input type="tel" /> years old
  <button id="stepBtn1" class="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/r7c1skgg/11/

There's something fundamental I'm not understanding here I'm sure, but the prevAll doc doesn't seem to spell the answer (I'm sure it's obvious).

Comment: `this` shouldn't be a string.

Comment: `$('this')` gets all `<this>` html elements. Instead, you probably wanted to wrap [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler) into a jQuery object wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , change the solution without define id.
The problem is the quote in $(this).prevAll not $('this')

```js
   $('.nextBtn').click(function() {
  alert($(this).prevAll('input[type=tel]').val());
})
```

```html
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="step" id="step1">
      <h2>How old are you?</h2>
      Answer: <input type="tel"/> years old
      <button id="stepBtn1" class="nextBtn">Next</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That would work in this instance. However, tis is a stripped down version of a larger quiz though which unfortunately that wouldn't work. Correct answer is in comment under question - can I mark this as correct some how? (Relating to incorrect 'this' usage)

Comment: This will work, but suggesting an `id` solution doesn't address the OP's main problem. Using an ID is not a magical solution for every _selector_-related problem.

Comment: change the solution without id